# Android application build faild after update com.android.tools.build:gradle from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

After update gradle-build-plugin from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1 build fails with the following exception on `:app:lint` task:

```
    09:38:53.491 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    09:38:53.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
    09:38:53.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
    09:38:53.494 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    09:38:53.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    09:38:53.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:995)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:121)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:969)
    09:38:53.497 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:59)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createUnitTestsJavaArtifact(ModelBuilder.java:615)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createVariant(ModelBuilder.java:501)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:379)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:196)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.AppModelBuilder.buildAll(AppModelBuilder.kt:71)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.createAndroidProject(LintGradleExecution.java:349)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:85)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:88)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintGlobalTask.lint(LintGlobalTask.java:47)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    09:38:53.498 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 29 more
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform
    09:38:53.499 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransformer.transform(UserCodeBackedTransformer.java:89)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformFileOperation.run(TransformFileOperation.java:40)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$900(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:50)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:359)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:202)
    09:38:53.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.waitForCompletion(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:116)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.executeInParallel(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:146)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.runAll(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:117)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.runAll(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:41)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:60)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:255)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:68)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:230)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    09:38:53.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:227)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:68)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:132)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:966)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 54 more
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor.(Unknown Source)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor.(Unknown Source)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode.(AnnotationNode.java:90)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode.(AnnotationNode.java:74)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.visitAnnotation(ClassNode.java:263)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    09:38:53.502 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.rewriteClass(MockableJarGenerator.java:133)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.createMockableJar(MockableJarGenerator.java:93)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.MockableJarTransform.transform(MockableJarTransform.java:54)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactsAction.apply(TransformArtifactsAction.java:44)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactsAction.apply(TransformArtifactsAction.java:29)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$TransformAction.execute(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:224)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$TransformAction.execute(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:211)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore$1.execute(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:91)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore$1.execute(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:87)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.doAdd(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:137)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.doAdd(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:127)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.add(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:87)
    09:38:53.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.add(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:50)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$1$1.create(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:143)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$1$1.create(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:122)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:89)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:193)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:158)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$1.create(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:122)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache$1.create(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:115)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache.loadIntoCache(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:115)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformedFileCache.getResult(DefaultTransformedFileCache.java:107)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransformer.transform(UserCodeBackedTransformer.java:87)
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 84 more
    09:38:53.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    09:38:53.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    09:38:53.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
    09:38:53.505 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 15s
    09:38:53.505 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 94 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 83 up-to-date
    09:38:53.508 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #0: shutdown
```

My build tool version is `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`
Other configs

```
ext {
  compileSdkVersion = 27
  supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
  minSdkVersion = 14
  targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

And `android` options are:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId ""
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
            versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        dexOptions {
            keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        android {
            lintOptions {
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
```

Comment: change the target sdk to 27

Comment: @GokulGowda it doesn't help ((

Comment: @RomanGordeev did you solve the issue?